# Swift encryption and NodeJS decryption producing inconsistent results

Tags: node.js, swift, encryption

I'm not very familiar with Crypto, but i did ensure that the iv length buffer returns the correct length, encryptionKey used are the same.

The expected result from NodeJS, is a preset IV Length of 16 randombytes + encryptedText generated with `aes-256-cbc` combined into a hex String of length 64.

Tests encrypting in Node and decrypting it produces the expected result. But when iOS sends the payload it decrypts into an unknown string.

However, when iOS encrypts and sends the data. I'm unable to decrypt it to get the expected string.

For iOS i'm using the CommonCryto library

```
import CommonCrypto

struct AES {

    private let key: String

    init?(key: String) {
        guard key.count == kCCKeySizeAES256 else {
            debugPrint("Error: Failed to set a key.")
            return nil
        }
        self.key = key
    }

    func encrypt(string: String) -> Data? {
        return crypt(data: string.data(using: .utf8), operation: kCCEncrypt)
    }

    private func crypt(data: Data?, operation: Int) -> Data? {
        guard let data = data else {
            return nil
        }

        var ivBytes: [UInt8]
        var inBytes: [UInt8]
        var outLength: Int

        if operation == kCCEncrypt {
            ivBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: kCCBlockSizeAES128)
            guard kCCSuccess == SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, ivBytes.count, &ivBytes) else {
                fatalError("IV creation failed!")
            }
            inBytes = Array(data)
            outLength = data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128
        } else {
            ivBytes = Array(Array(data).dropLast(data.count - kCCBlockSizeAES128))
            inBytes = Array(Array(data).dropFirst(kCCBlockSizeAES128))
            outLength = inBytes.count
        }

        var outBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: outLength)
        var bytesMutated = 0

        guard kCCSuccess == CCCrypt(CCOperation(operation), CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES), CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), Array(key), key.count, &ivBytes, &inBytes, inBytes.count, &outBytes, outLength, &bytesMutated) else {
            fatalError("Cryptography operation \(operation) failed")
        }

        var outData = Data(bytes: &outBytes, count: bytesMutated)

        if operation == kCCEncrypt {
            ivBytes.append(contentsOf: Array(outData))
            outData = Data(ivBytes)
        }
        return outData
    }
}
```

And how i decrypt in NodeJS:

```
const decrypt = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const uid = context && context.auth && context.auth.uid;
    if(!uid) {
        return sendErrorResponse({
            payload: 'Unauthorised',
            statusCode: 401,
        });
    }
    const { password } = data;

    const MID = password.length / 2;
    const textPart = [password.slice(0,MID),password.slice(MID)];
    const iv = Buffer.from(textPart.shift(),'hex');
    const encryptedText = Buffer.from(textPart.join(),'hex');
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey, iv).setAutoPadding(false);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
    return decrypted.toString();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for cross plate-form [AES encryption](http://blog.webzites.nl/index.php/2017/04/11/aes-encryption-node-js-swift-android/)